# How can I detect the indentation of previous line at cursor in vim

Tags: vim, indentation

I wrote the following command in my `vimrc`, which prints the value of a variable together with the variable name itself.

```
command -nargs=1 Pv :normal i        print("<args>:", <args>)<ESC>
```

I use it usually for debugging in my python programs. However, I would like that the `print` command inserts aligned with the indentation of the previous line so that I don't need to move it. Is there any command for such thing?

Answer (score 0):

If the `autoindent` is on, then the command cab be as the following:

```
command -nargs=1 Pv :normal oprint("<args>:", <args>)<ESC>
```